# Youtube API: inserting a video item in a watch history playlist using api v3

Tags: python, youtube-api

I did try this API: (insert)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#try-it

and got a 200OK and a json revising what I've insert correctly.
what I specified is the video resource (kind, id) and a playlistId which is my 'watchhistory'.

The strange thing is I cannot see the new result when I do a list (GET) with the corresponding api calls. However, if I actually go to youtube.com, I see the new item which I never watch, in my watch history appearing the  right order (newest). But my objective is to still be able to get this information with the api calls. Anybody experience similar things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to an internal engineering issue concerning the API not reporting the full watch history. It's something that they've been working on for a few months now, with limited success (they've pushed a couple of changes, but it hasn't remedied the problem). Basically, until it is fixed, the v3 watch history only returns an older, incomplete subset of the actual history.

Here's the issue if you want to track it or contribute to the data to help resolve it:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4642